# The mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^{2,3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_3$ is given by the formula. Answer the questions about it.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{2,3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_3$ be the mapping and given by the formula
$$F(A)(x) = [1, x] \cdot A \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x ^{2}  \end{bmatrix}, \text{ for } A \in\mathbb{R} ^{2, 3}.$$ 
(a) Prove that $F$ is a linear transformation from the space $\mathbb{R}^{2,3}$ to the space $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$ (both over the field $\mathbb{R}$). 
(b) Determine the basis of the subspace $ker F$. 
(c) Give an example of a subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{2,3}$ (indicating its basis) such that $F|_V \in L(V, \mathbb{R}[x]_3)$ is an isomorphism, or prove that such a subspace $V$ does not exist.

Comment: Please explain your notation.

Comment: What exactly do I need to explain? And also what do you mean by "my notation"? I am not a native speaker)

Comment: For (b), what is the kernel of a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$, where $V,W$ are vector spaces? More precisely, what kind of elements should it contain?

Comment: It should contain a set of vectors in $V$ that gives zero vector in $W$. And I saw that there should be smth like $L(\overline{v} =...)$ and then we should equal to $0$ what we get from $L(\overline{v})$ and find kernel. But I don't know, where is this $L(\overline{v})$ in my problem? :/

Comment: Are you applying $\;F(A)\;$ ...on what?! What *exactly* is $\;[1,x]\;$ ? Is that the very specific polynomial $\;1+x\;$ ? But if it is, then how is $\;F(A)\;$ defined on a general polynomial of degree lower than $\;3\;$ ?

Comment: @Donald What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}^{2,3}$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$?

Comment: @DonAntonio Honestly I don't understand meaning of $[1, x]$ too(

Comment: @Donald I'd say that $\;[a,b]\;$ should be a coordinates vector representing a polynomial, for example the linear one: $\;a+bx\;$ . But you use $\;x\;$ as the polynomials' varialbe and also as an entry of the supposed coordinate vector...it confuses me.

Comment: For (b): Let say $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $F(A)(x) = fx³ + (c+e)x² + (b+d)x + a$. The kernel of $F$ have to be the subspace such that $f=0$, $c+3=0$, $b+d=0$ and $a$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @DonAntonio Is confusion in the task or in my proof?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&x\end{bmatrix}$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix. You multiply it by $A$ and then by the (column) vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\x\\x^2\end{bmatrix}$. The result is a polynomial of degree at most $3$ (sitting as a $1\times 1$ matrix). When do you get the *zero* polynomial as the answer?

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari I don't exactly understand how you came to $F(A)(x) = ...$ Could you please answer my question (not in comments) so I can see?

Comment: Is waht @TedShifrin say, I only make the matricial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\Bbb R^{2,3}$ and $\Bbb R[x]_3$ denote the set of all $2$-by-$3$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb R$ and the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb R$ and degree at most $3$, respectively.

**a) Linear transformation**: Let $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $A,B\in\Bbb R^{2,3}$. Then
$$F(\alpha A+B)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \end{pmatrix}\left(\alpha A+B\right)\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}\\
=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \end{pmatrix}B\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}\\
=\alpha F(A)+F(B),$$
where we have used the product-with-a-scalar and distributivity properties of matrices.

**b) The kernel of $F$**: The kernel of $F$ is the set
$$\ker(F)=\{A\in\Bbb R^{2,3}\vert F(A)=0\}.$$
Define $A\in\Bbb R^{2,3}$ as
$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then we can show that
$$F(A)=0\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}=0\\
\Rightarrow a_{11}+(a_{12}+a_{21})x+(a_{13}+a_{22})x^2+a_{23}x^3=0.$$
Since $1,x,x^2,x^3$ is linearly independent, we obtain
$$a_{11}=0 \ ; \ a_{12}=-a_{21} \ ; \ a_{13}=-a_{22} \ ; \ a_{23}=0.$$
Therefore,
$$\ker(F)=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ -a_{12} & -a_{13} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\vert a_{12},a_{13}\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$
It is not hard to show that $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ is a basis for $\ker(F)$.

**c) Isomorphism**: Note that
$$F\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right)=1;\\
F\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right)=x;\\
F\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right)=x^2;\\
F\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)=x^3.$$
Define $V\subset\Bbb R^{2,3}$ as
$$V=\text{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$
It follows that $\left.F\right\vert_V\in L(V,\Bbb R[x]_3)$ and it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! It is very good. I have some questions for better understanding: My proof for (a) was bad or you just gave your variant? How to show that $1, x^1, x^2, x^3$ are linearly independent? Or we have shown it in (a)?

Comment: @Donald To show that $1,x,x^2,x^3$ is linearly independent, we have to show that $$(*) \ \ \ c_01+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3=0$$ implies $c_0=c_1=c_2=c_3=0$. By plugging $x = 0$ into $(*)$, we see that $c_0 = 0$. Taking the derivative of both sides of $(*)$ then reveals that $$c_1+2c_2x+3c_3x^2=0$$ and plugging $x = 0$ into this equation gives $c_1 = 0$. By repeating this
procedure we similarly see that $c_2=c_3=0$. Therefore, $1,x,x^2,x^3$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @Donald The ideia is right, but your last equation should be corrected to $$F(A + B)(x) = [1, x] \cdot (A + B) \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x ^{2}  \end{bmatrix} = [1, x] \cdot A \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x ^{2}  \end{bmatrix} + [1, x]\cdot B\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x ^{2}  \end{bmatrix}=F(A)(x)+F(B)(x) $$